# How do I get a Double with a default value to be blank/empty in a form field in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a form in SwiftUI where one of the fields in a Double.

If I set `@State private var qty: Double = 0` then the form field, naturally, has a default of `0`. But when adding a new item, I want that field to just be blank.

[image]

If I just remove the default and make it `@State private var qty: Double`, then an error is thrown.

[image]

Comment: Post code as text.

Comment: And `nil` will generate an empty field so make the property optional

Answer (score 1):

How about making the property optional?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var amount: Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Amount", value: $amount, format: .number)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```